# Unable to create connection pool for SQL Server 2012 using context.xml file and Microsoft JDBC driver

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, sql-server-2012

This is the first time I am using SQL Server, previously I was working on MySQL and I was creating db connection pool in tomcat successfully. I am trying to use same code to create a connection pool for sql server. Please guide me where I am going wrong.

I am trying login as Windows Authentication, I have copied sqljdbc_auth.dll in tomcat bin directory.

Following is the code I wrote in my context.xml file under META-INF:

```
Context antiJARLocking="true" path="">
    <Resource 
    auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
    logAbandoned="true"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="30" 
    maxWait="1000" 
    name="jdbc/mydb" 
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;" />
</Context>
```

And below is the java class which is providing connections:

```
public class ConnectionPool {
private static ConnectionPool pool=null;
private static DataSource dataSource = null;

public synchronized static ConnectionPool getInstance(){
    if (pool == null){
        pool = new ConnectionPool();
    }
    return pool;
}

private ConnectionPool(){
    try{
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}


public Connection getConnection(){
    try{
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle){
        System.err.println(sqle);
        return null;
    }
}

public void freeConnection(Connection c){
    try{
        c.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle){
        System.err.println(sqle);
    }
}
}
```

When I tried calling `getConnection()` then I got following exception:
`javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:39)`

Comment: Java doesn't work with DLLs directly, instead with jars. It looks that you need to add the jar to connect with your SQL Server. I used [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) to connect with it.